# How to change the action of NSColorWell?

Tags: xcode, swift3, nscolorwell

I can use NSColorWell as button to change the color of selected text. Since NSColorWell is object of an NSControl it has target and action. I guess, the action is implementing the code to change the color of the selected text in NSTextView. Where can I find this code for NSColorWell action?  I would like to change it in away that I can use NSColorWell to change the background of the selected text, and ultimately to have in ToolBar two NSColorWell buttons: one to change text's foreground color and second one for text's background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSColorWell` is just a rectangular control to change a color.

- You can either create an `IBAction` and connect it to the action of the color well  in the Connections Inspector (<kbd>⌥⌘6</kbd>) of Interface Builder

  ```
  @IBAction func changeColor(_ sender : NSColorWell)
  {
     let color = sender.color
     // do something with the color
  }
  ```
- Or bind the `value` in Bindings Inspector (<kbd>⌥⌘7</kbd>) of Interface Builder to a `dynamic` property, this example will set the color well to a default value of green.

  ```
  dynamic var color : NSColor = .green {
     didSet {
       // do something with the color
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: Ok, If I understand correctly you suggest to use color from  NSColorWell to change the foreground or background color of attributed  string by putting the standard code for this in the IBAction changeColor ? But, will it stop changing the foreground color when I change the background color. Now it is changing the foreground color automatically when I press NSColorWell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To avoid the automatic text colouring, by default, in IB the uses Font Panel check box should be off (or usesFontPanel should be set to false in viewDidLoad())